# Hadoop: Cannot Launch Daemons

Tags: hadoop, daemons

I am having trouble launching daemons in my pseduo-distributed hadoop configuration. I type in the following command:

**sudo bin/start-all.sh**

I get prompts to enter my password, but once I do that, I get this error message

```
root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.
```

I tried to change ownership of hadoop to local user using chown command. However I am still getting this annoying error. And I am trying to invoke this script in root mode.

Where am I going wrong here? I searched online everywhere, there doesn't seem to be enough experience with hadoop to answer my question.

You responses are really appreciated..

Comment: Ok looks like I had to set up a password for my root.

The following command did the trick.

    sudo passwd

It then prompts for new UNIX password & to enter it again to confirm. Once you do that bin/start-all.sh will work fine with the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up password-less ssh? It not set up password-less ssh for localhost.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa     
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```